# How to create(export) excel file readonly using Open Xml 2.5 SDK

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, openxml-sdk

I am developing one WPF application (using MVVM). I am also able to export my List to Excel file.But my problem is  I am not able to make it readonly, so no one can able to make changes afterwards.

```
document.WorkbookPart.Workbook.WorkbookProtection=new WorkbookProtection
                                                          {
                                                               LockStructure=true
                                                          };
```

I only found this, but it's only make workbook readonly

Here is my code for creating excel file

```
public static bool CreateExcelDocument(DataSet ds, string excelFilename)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(excelFilename, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
            {
                document.AddWorkbookPart();
                document.WorkbookPart.Workbook = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Workbook();
                document.WorkbookPart.Workbook.WorkbookProtection=new WorkbookProtection
                                                                      {
                                                                          LockStructure = true,
                                                                      };

                //  My thanks to James Miera for the following line of code (which prevents crashes in Excel 2010)
                document.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Append(new BookViews(new WorkbookView()));

                //  If we don't add a "WorkbookStylesPart", OLEDB will refuse to connect to this .xlsx file !
                WorkbookStylesPart workbookStylesPart = document.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>("rIdStyles");
                Stylesheet stylesheet = new Stylesheet();
                workbookStylesPart.Stylesheet = stylesheet;

                CreateParts(ds, document);
            }
            Trace.WriteLine("Successfully created: " + excelFilename);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("Failed, exception thrown: " + ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }

    private static void CreateParts(DataSet ds, SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheet)
    {
        //  Loop through each of the DataTables in our DataSet, and create a new Excel Worksheet for each.
        uint worksheetNumber = 1;
        foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
        {
            //  For each worksheet you want to create
            string workSheetID = "rId" + worksheetNumber.ToString();
            string worksheetName = dt.TableName;

            WorksheetPart newWorksheetPart = spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
            newWorksheetPart.Worksheet = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Worksheet();

            // create sheet data
            newWorksheetPart.Worksheet.AppendChild(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.SheetData());

            // save worksheet
            WriteDataTableToExcelWorksheet(dt, newWorksheetPart);
            newWorksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();

            // create the worksheet to workbook relation
            if (worksheetNumber == 1)
                spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets());

            spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets>().AppendChild(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet()
            {
                Id = spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(newWorksheetPart),
                SheetId = (uint)worksheetNumber,
                Name = dt.TableName
            });

            worksheetNumber++;
        }

        spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you open Excel, you can Lock your file with:

```
FileInfo cInfo = new FileInfo(Path);
cInfo.IsReadonly = true;
```

Than it will be readonly.

Comment: It is a good solution, but do you know how to do it using Open Xml SDK at the time of creation.

Comment: I dont't think that this is possibly. But does this help: [Open a spreadsheet document for read-only access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc823095.aspx) ?

Comment: I already seen that. So I don't think any thing else is available. 
If I didn't get any answer within few days then I will mark this as answer because I think it is best solution if Open Xml doesn't provide any thing.